# Python: Attribute error on method call in variable assignment, but not in print

Tags: python

I have been encountering an error in my code that has me completely baffled and would appreciate any help.

I have a class foo with a method `getTitle()` that returns a string.

I have made repeated calls to this method on numerous instances of foo in my script with no issue, then all of a sudden with one instance, a, when I call `c = a.getTitle()` I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getTitle'
```

The thing that is really puzzling me is that when I put `print a.getTitle()` immediately above the call `c = a.getTitle()` it prints the string properly before throwing the error on `c = a.getTitle()`.

I've also tried `print type(a)` to verify that it's an instance of class foo and it works properly.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: can you put a breakpoint on c = a.getTitle() and inspect the value of a at that point?